# How to release memory in cocos2d app

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I have used

```
-(void)dealloc{

   [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeSpriteFrames];
   [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
   [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
   [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];

   [super dealloc];
}
```

in every scene of the cocos2d app. But cant see any memory release. Still it gives memory warning. I don't know is that because CCBReader library. What is the most appropriate way to release unused objects in these type of situations.

Comment: Brute force approaches like this don't work well. You will want to release only the resources you know are no longer being used. Overzealously trying to release memory can also cause additional loading time, as cached resources are thrown away and reloaded again almost instantly. This in turn can cause you to receive even more memory warnings, because loading textures in cocos2d requires at least twice the texture memory (the image data, and the texture constructed from the image data are both in memory at the same time during load).

Comment: what is your process for 'seeing' memory release ? these are all autorelease objects, and the memory release will eventually occur when the runloop has cycled, so you cant see the effect immediately (for example while stepping in debug).  Add a [[CCTextureCache] sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo] immediately after the purges. You will get confirmation that the dealloc is invoked.